# C# Call single method multiple times simultaneously

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I have a Method which calls a Web Service.

```
function void SendAsync( object input )
{
     // Log Time Before Send to WebService (T1)
     ......  Call WebMethod ....
     // Log Time After Send to WebService (T2)
}
```

I want to run a loop and call the Web method with different Input data.
Without waiting for the response I want to keep on calling the Web Method.

```
for ( int i=1;i<=100;i++ )
{ 
            //LOG TIME BEFORE Calling Async Method (T0)

            //TRIAL 1
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(t.SendAsync), i.ToString());

            //TRIAL 2
            new Task(() => { SendAsync(i.ToString()); }).Start();

            //TRIAL 3
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SendAsync(i.ToString()));

            //TRIAL 4
            AsyncTask_Delegate adel = null;
            adel = new AsyncTask_Delegate(SendAsync);
            IAsyncResult R = null;
            R = adel.BeginInvoke(i.ToString(), null, null); //invoking the method
}
```

I want to call this function as Async call.
I have tried various approaches as mentioned above.

The time between T0 and T1 is quite substantial (Even in 15-40 Seconds).
Next Method call is happening in the loop, but the actual Call to the Web method is getting delayed.
The method is not running concurrently.
I even put the SendAsync method in different class and call the method still the same result.....

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

---

Thank you all for your responses.

Adding more light on the problem is that I am creating an input string during each loop and sending it to a function for processing.

Also instead of Calling a Web Method even when we call a normal simple method, the difference between T0 and T1 is large.

The same function is running in Async mode but simply not able to run or start simultaneously.

I have tried to create a copy like "var tmp=i;" before calling, but delay is still present.

Comment: Why not send all the data in one single call?

Comment: You mean `SendAsync` is invoked sometime later?

Comment: Your requests are likely being queued and processed individually at your destination.  By default IIS will only handle one .NET request at a time, you'd have to increase the number of workers.

Comment: Just by curiosity, why would you want to do that?

Comment: Hi ,
 I have currently a set of Data in a DataTable.
 I have a third party Web Service which requires a string formatted in particular format as input for processing.
 I am currently parsing the string and sending it to Webservice on Row by Row basis.
 The Web service takes some amount of time.
 Instead of waiting for the response I want to keep on sending the rest of the data for processing as such maximum data can be processed in minimum time.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect it *is* running concurrently - but that the degree of concurrency is being limited by the HTTP connection pool.

You might to change [`ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit.aspx) or set it in your app.config with the [`<connectionManagement>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb6y0fyc(v=vs.110).aspx) element.

Additionally, note that these lines are suspect:

```
new Task(() => { SendAsync(i.ToString()); }).Start();
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SendAsync(i.ToString()));
```

In both cases you're capturing `i`, which is being update by the main thread. You need to capture a *copy* of the value of `i` for that iteration:

```
int x = i;
new Task(() => { SendAsync(x.ToString()); }).Start();
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SendAsync(x.ToString()));
```

Otherwise you may well see `SendAsync("2")` twice and no call to `SendAsync("1")` for example.

Comment: Not my question but, in this case, even setting the HTTP connection pool to the maximum would not guarantee the calls are made concurrently. I mean, wouldn't the network itself limit the communication?

Comment: The default value for DefaultConnectionLimit is 2 so would he at least see two go through quickly if this was the only blockage? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit.aspx

Comment: @MikeCheel: Well, the QueueUserWorkItem would lead to waiting for the thread pool to warm up, which could create a 1 second lag - but my point is that the OP would see *most* of the requests have a big gap between T0 and T1.

Comment: So you're saying you wouldn't see the first two because of the start up delay. Makes sense. I guess increasing the DefaultConnectionLimit would then allow you to rule out (or in) other issue causing the tasks to run sync.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on async, but i think you want something like this:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
for(int i = 0; i< 100; i ++)
    tasks.Add(Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() => SendAsync(i), i));

Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This might be late, but your method was useful to me, except you would have to use `Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());`.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me and runs async:

```
void Main()
{
    for ( int i=1;i<=100;i++ )
    { 
        var tmp = i; // this line is needed, you might get the same value for variable i for several calls otherwize!
        Task.Run(() => { SendAsync(tmp.ToString()); });
    }
}
```